# Browsersync stream function behaviour

Tags: javascript, stream, gulp, browser-sync

I've came on interesting problem, I think.
When calling in gulp this task:

```
gulp.task("cssReload",function () {
    browserSync.stream();
});
```

It does not work. 
However, if I call:

```
gulp.task("cssReload",function () {
    gulp.src("")
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

BrowserSync Stream function works as it should. Is it expected behavior and I'm missing something?

For me it looks like the first approach should also work. Can somebody explain me what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is expected behavior. You are tracking changes by using gulp.src() and piping reload.

You can also look at this simple example for inspiritaion. 
https://github.com/atilkan/gulp-typescript-stylus-template/blob/master/gulpfile.js

```
var browserSync   = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload        = browserSync.reload;
var gulp          = require('gulp');

gulp.watch('dev/css/**/*.css', ['cssReload']);

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dev/'
        }
    });
});



gulp.task('cssReload', function() {
    gulp.src('dev/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'cssReload']);
```

Comment: I gave you the example. If this is correct you could mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @Bartosz546 your continued misunderstanding does not detract from the correctness of this answer, nor does it prevent you from marking it as correct.

Comment: After 2 years. You are not using correctly. You have to pipe the resources to gulp so it can detect file changes. AFAIR.